# vBulletin 4.x External Page Login and Variables

Tags: authentication, vbulletin

I've been searching around and experimenting with this for hours, with no success.

I'm trying to login to vBulletin from an external page. I've managed to get this to work. However what I can't get to work is showing the username and any of the $vbulletin variables.

I've included global.php chdir() to the forum etc etc, but I just can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is working example i'm using it. Its working fine. Its show user name and logout button on External page.

I don't know why -vote it.

```
<?php
    $curdir = getcwd();
    #Add your root dir below where it says "ADD ROOT" Example: /home/server/public_html/mainsite/forums
    #Do not end with a "/" leave it open like above example.
    chdir('ADD ROOT');
    require_once('ADD ROOT/global.php');
    chdir($curdir);
    if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == 0) {
    #Form Display Code, You can edit the way the Form is layed out here.
      echo "<form id=\"login\" action=\"/forums/login.php?do=login\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)\">
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=364\"></script>
    <a href=\"/forums/register.php\">Register</a>
    <label for=\"navbar_username\">Username</label>
    <input type=\"text\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_username\" id=\"navbar_username\" size=\"10\" accesskey=\"u\" tabindex=\"101\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == 'User Name') this.value = '';\" />
    <label for=\"navbar_password\">Password</label>
    <input type=\"password\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_password\" id=\"navbar_password\" size=\"10\" tabindex=\"102\" />
    <label for=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cookieuser\" value=\"1\" tabindex=\"103\" id=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\" accesskey=\"c\" />Remember Me?</label>
    <input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Login\" tabindex=\"104\" title=\"Enter your username and password in the boxes provided to login, or click the 'register' button to create a profile for yourself.\" accesskey=\"s\" />
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"s\" value=\"\" />
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"do\" value=\"login\" />        
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"vb_login_md5password\" />
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"vb_login_md5password_utf\" />
    </form>";
    #End Form Display Code
    } else {
    #Display after login completed
      echo "Welcome Back, <b>".$vbulletin->userinfo['username']."</b>";
      if ($vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] == '6' ) {
      echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/member.php?1-".$vbulletin->userinfo['username']."\">My Profile</a>";
      echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/egncadmincp/index.php\">AdminCP</a>";
      echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/egncmodcp/index.php\">ModCP</a>";
      }
    }
    ?>
```